# I want to create my own model urdf file and run it in rviz

Tags: rviz

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm a beginner and trying to learn ROS. I know how to create a urdf file, catkin workspace and package. But not sure on how to run that urdf file in rviz. Basically I'd like to know how to create launch files without using any tutorial package launch folder.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/259362/i-want-to-create-my-own-model-urdf-file-and-run-it-in-rviz/) by [shbhmsin](https://answers.ros.org/users/30044/shbhmsin/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2017-04-16

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Have you looked through the [urdf tutorials](http://wiki.ros.org/urdf/Tutorials)?

They show you how to launch a urdf in rviz:

```
$ roslaunch urdf_tutorial display.launch model:='$(find urdf_tutorial)/urdf/01-myfirst.urdf'
```

If you don't want to use the urdf_tutorial package (I think that's what you're saying) simply copy the display.launch file from the urdf_tutorial package and paste it in your own package, then you're free to edit it if you like. You'll see there's not much in there:

```
<launch>

  <arg name="model" default="$(find urdf_tutorial)/urdf/r2d2.xacro"/>
  <arg name="gui" default="true" />
  <arg name="rvizconfig" default="$(find urdf_tutorial)/rviz/urdf.rviz" />

  <param name="robot_description" command="$(find xacro)/xacro.py $(arg model)" />
  <param name="use_gui" value="$(arg gui)"/>

  <node name="joint_state_publisher" pkg="joint_state_publisher" type="joint_state_publisher" />
  <node name="robot_state_publisher" pkg="robot_state_publisher" type="state_publisher" />
  <node name="rviz" pkg="rviz" type="rviz" args="-d $(arg rvizconfig)" required="true" />

</launch>
```

It's just starting all the nodes you'll need to show the robot in Rviz (and move the joints)

---

Originally posted by [Airuno2L](https://answers.ros.org/users/458/airuno2l/) with karma: 3460 on 2017-04-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0